# Trouble with subscribing to keyspace notifications

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a list in redis managed by [bull](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bull). I'd like to monitor the length of this list a different process. I'm new to redis so while I think I've found the "correct" way to do this, I'm running into issues.

From a little research I leaned that Redis has Keyspace Notifications from 2.8.0 onwards and they sounded appropriate.

Before I go further I just want to confirm I have keyspace events enabled:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET notify-keyspace-events
1) "notify-keyspace-events"
2) "AKE"
```

Also, according to `INFO`, I think I'm on database 0:

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=315,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

With that out of the way: I'm having trouble subscribing to the channels I want. The module creates and manages a list under the key: 'bull:Test Queue:wait', so based on the documentation for keyspace notifications my understanding is I should be doing the following to listen to push and pop events.

1. `SUBSCRIBE "__keyspace:0__:bull:Test Queue:wait rpush"`
2. `SUBSCRIBE "__keyspace:0__:bull:Test Queue:wait lpush"`
3. `SUBSCRIBE "__keyspace:0__:bull:Test Queue:wait rpop"`
4. `SUBSCRIBE "__keyspace:0__:bull:Test Queue:wait lpop"`

If I run 1. in one process, and then in another process do:

```
RPUSH "bull:Test Queue:wait" 222
```

Then the subscribe doesn't get the message. Weirdly, if I use `PSUBSCRIBE` and listen to `"__keyspace:0__:bull:Test Queue:wait*"` then it *does* fire appropriately. But I'm not looking for all events, just pushes and pops. So this isn't quite what I'm after.

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding the docs.

The channel is `__keyspace:0__:bull:Test Queue:wait` and the message is `rpush`, `lpush`, etc. Alternatively, the channel could be: `__keyspace:0__:rpush` and the message would be `bull:Test Queue:wait`.

Thank to Jan-Erik Rediger who [helped me out on the discussion board](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/o7sGpwUB9BI).